Having issues with getting a plot of time-dependent AUCs
I am working on a question for class and I am stuck on problem 2 of my homework which is asking:
"Obtain a plot of time-dependent AUCs at times 100, 200, 300, . . . , 5000."
I have attached my code that I have so far below:
library(survival)
library(timeROC)

# Load the data
data(flchain)

data <- survival::flchain[
  complete.cases(survival::flchain[, c('age', 'sex', 'sample.yr', 'kappa', 'lambda', 'flc.grp', 'creatinine', 'mgus')]),]

# Question 1: Fit Cox PH + Concordance index for model
cox_model <- coxph(Surv(futime, death) ~ age + sex + sample.yr + kappa + lambda + flc.grp + creatinine + mgus, data=data)
c_index <- (1 - (cox_model$loglik[2] / cox_model$loglik[1]))
print(paste("Concordance Index for Cox PH Model:", round(c_index, 3)))

# Question 2: Time-dependent AUCs
time_points <- seq(100, 5000, by = 100)
aucs <- lapply(time_points, function(t) {
  roc_obj <- timeROC(predictor = fitted(cox_model), time = t, status = data$death)
  return(auc(roc_obj))
})
plot(time_points, aucs, type = 'l', xlab = 'Time', ylab = 'AUC')

I am struggling to get the timeROC part to work. I am not sure if I am missing something or even using the correct library for this problem. I have tried a few different ways of doing this. I have used this:
timeROC(T, delta, marker, other_markers = NULL, cause,
        weighting = "marginal", times, ROC = TRUE, iid = FALSE)


Every time I try to run it, it states that my vectors are not the same size even though they are when I have checked.
I have also looked at using this:
plotAUCcurve(object, FP = 2, add = FALSE, conf.int = FALSE,
             conf.band = FALSE, col = "black")

However, I have also tried to run this but it has also not worked because I cannot get the timeROC function to work. I am at a loss of how to figure this out.
